# html table to csv scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv

I'm trying to scrape the table in the following website but was not able to do it:

https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/relianceindustries/ratiosVI/RI?classic=true#RI

```
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import urlopen

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/relianceindustries/ratiosVI/RI?classic=true#RI'))

table = soup.find('table', attrs={ "class" : "table-horizontal-line"})

headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]

rows = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text.encode('utf8') for val in row.find_all('td')])

with open('output_file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Any errors?

Comment: Which part of your code fails? Can you access the site? Can you find the table? Can you extract the rows? Can you write the csv?

Comment: Try doing `something = table.find_all('tr')' on a separate line, then go into the loop `for row in something:` but that's my best guess without more information on whats wrong

Comment: I take it you mean "scrape" and "scraper".  Anyway, are you sure "table-horizontal-line" is not only in the code, but a class of the table itself and not for example a row or other tag?  I don't see it when I look at the page's code.  There might be a better way to identify the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas for this. There are a couple of rows at the top you may wish to remove and replace some other NaNs with empty strings as cleansing.

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.read_html('https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/relianceindustries/ratiosVI/RI?classic=true#RI')
df = result[3].dropna(how='all').fillna('')
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )
```